# Custom redeemable voucher code for lower subscription price

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, in-app-subscription, revenuecat

I have an application with features that I would like to lock for users without a subscription. My client would like to give voucher codes for influencers to spread it for their users. In the application there is a section for buy the subscription with an input field to enter the voucher code. In the app store I've set up a Subscription Group with 2 different subscription. Both are annual subscription but they have different prices.

- premium_full 2$
- premium_gift 1$

**The mechanism:** We have a database where we store the custom voucher codes. When the user wants to buy the subscription with a valid entered voucher code, then in the application I choose the subscription plan with the lower price. The IAP is handled by Revenuecat.

It is important to use custom and re-usable codes since we need to benchmark how many times they have been used.

This scenario works on the Google Play platform but I found out via App review that it is not an acceptable approach in App Store

Can you suggest an example how should I change the functionality to keep the desired mechanism? Or is there any bestpractise regarding this topic?

Thanks!

Comment: The App Store has its own [offer codes](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-subscriptions/set-up-offer-codes) system.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. But those are "One-time-use codes".

Comment: Did you read the page I linked to? "Custom codes: Uniquely named custom codes — for example, SPRINGPROMO — each of which can be redeemed through a redemption URL or within your app on iOS 14.1 or iPadOS 14 or later (if your app supports the presentCodeRedemptionSheet method). You can set a maximum redemption limit and choose whether or not to set an expiration date. Custom codes are ideal for large campaigns that require mass distribution"

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I missed that part. Thanks for highlighting it.